# Scene builder doesn't open file

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

Everybody! 
Again coming back for your wise advices, Java Proes)
I just started working with Scene Builder and while trying to open an FXML file i got dieser problem:

```html
java.io.IOException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 15; columnNumber: 15; XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
 at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.glue.GlueLoader.load(GlueLoader.java:93)
 at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.glue.GlueLoader.load(GlueLoader.java:76)
 at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.glue.GlueDocument.<init>(GlueDocument.java:54)
 at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMDocument.<init>(FXOMDocument.java:74)
 at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMDocument.<init>(FXOMDocument.java:95)
 at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.EditorController.updateFxomDocument(EditorController.java:2370)
 at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.EditorController.setFxmlTextAndLocation(EditorController.java:655)
 at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.DocumentWindowController.loadFromFile(DocumentWindowController.java:386)
 at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.performOpenFiles(SceneBuilderApp.java:579)
 at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.performOpenFile(SceneBuilderApp.java:525)
 at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.performControlAction(SceneBuilderApp.java:201)
 at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.menubar.MenuBarController$ApplicationControlActionController.perform(MenuBarController.java:1658)
 at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.menubar.MenuBarController.handleOnActionMenu(MenuBarController.java:1115)
 at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.menubar.MenuBarController.access$800(MenuBarController.java:90)
 at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.menubar.MenuBarController$20.handle(MenuBarController.java:1108)
 at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.menubar.MenuBarController$20.handle(MenuBarController.java:1104)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
 at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:204)
 at javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.fire(MenuItem.java:462)
 at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(ContextMenuContent.java:1344)
 at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(ContextMenuContent.java:1319)
 at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer$7.handle(ContextMenuContent.java:1287)
 at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer$7.handle(ContextMenuContent.java:1285)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
 at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:204)
 at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3746)
 at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1800(Scene.java:3471)
 at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1695)
 at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2486)
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:314)
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:243)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:345)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:526)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:898)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(WinApplication.java:39)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(WinApplication.java:112)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 15; columnNumber: 15; XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:441)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1436)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.endEntity(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:903)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.endEntity(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:563)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.endEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1387)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(XMLEntityScanner.java:1783)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.scanData(XMLEntityScanner.java:1288)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanPIData(XMLScanner.java:741)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanPIData(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1018)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanPI(XMLScanner.java:691)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:912)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
 at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.glue.GlueLoader.load(GlueLoader.java:91)
 ... 58 more
```

Well, after 10 minutes I added this erorr It started to seem to be realy stupid question, and I don't really know what i'm hoping for...
But I would be extremely glad if someone would tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the FXML?

Comment: Okay,okay,okay,
I'm A Dumb, i just had a little mistake in my code.
Thanks for paying attention thow , anyways)
P.S.How can i close this Topic?

Comment: Just delete the question